# How to make a long highway in unity?

Tags: unity

I'm planning to make a long highway for a Racer game. What is the best way to do it ?

Do you make it in a single scene which I think is difficult to manage ? Or do you make multiple scenes or anything else ?

Comment: How long is "long"? From which perspective does the player see it? Does it curve?

Comment: its mostly straight with little curves. the player sees it from first person angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to chunk up your large level into multiple smaller levels. Then, depending at what point on the track the player is on, load and unload sub-levels as needed to provide the illusion of one larger level. This essentially involves using the Unity Scene as a 2nd level prefab.

You can load a scene into your current scene with SceneManager.LoadLevel() and SceneManager.LoadLevelAsync() but making sure to pass the LoadSceneMode.Additive parameter.

Here are some links to those methods on the Unity docs:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html

Here's a slightly out of date answer on the Unity stack exchange. Same principle applies but Application.LoadLevelAddative was just made obsolete.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/223782/prefab-of-a-whole-scene.html

Answer (score 2):

Beside an applicable but tough solution of Honeybunch, I think that your question can be answer through developing an infinite road dyanmically which can be consider as endless runner type of game. Please have a look

1. [3D Infinite Runner Game Tutorial](http://coffeebreakcodes.com/sample-projects-unity/3d-infinite-runner-game-tutorial-unity3d/)
2. [Lets Make a Game: Infinite Runner](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/lets-make-game-infinite-runner)
3. [Creating an infinite 3D runner game in Unity (like Temple Run, Subway Surfers)](https://dgkanatsios.com/2016/03/07/creating-an-infinite-3d-runner-game-in-unity-like-temple-run-subway-surfers-part-1/)
4. [Your Own Subway Surfer/Temple Run Like Game](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/p/your-own-subway.html)